# How 'MOD' the binary operation works with floor function?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, binary-operations

I was looking for some example on MOD and floor function from Concrete Mathematics book(1). But, the solution of each example is very confusing for me.

The general formula of x mod y is;

x mod y = x - y(lfloor (x / y) rfloor)  [for y is not equal to 0]

Here, lfloor means left floor and rfloor means right floor

I know, how it works when value of x and y is positive. But, I get confused when value of x or y or both becomes negative.

Examples from the book(1):

```
5 mod -3 = 5 - (-3)(lfloor (5 / (-3)) rfloor) = -1

-5 mod 3 = -5 -3(lfloor (-5 / 3) rfloor) = 1

-5 mod -3 = -5 - (-3)(lfloor (-5 / (-3)) rfloor) = -2
```

*Resource:*

(1) [Book - Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf) See page 95

Comment: What you do not understand in the negative case?

Comment: @Raito how answer -1 is coming from example 1 here. But from my calculation answer comes positive 1. I multiplied -3 with 5 and then divided quotient by -3. Then the answer 5 in floor function becomes 4. Then finally I subtracted 4 from 5 and got final answer 1. I am confused the procedure of calculation I applied.

Comment: $$5\text{ mod }-3=5-(-3)\left\lfloor\frac5{-3}\right\rfloor=5-(-3)(-2)=5-6=-1$$

Comment: @PeterForeman how floor (5 / (-3)) comes -2. Generally (5 / 3) =  1.667 If we floor 1.667 then I think we should get 1. Am i wrong?

Comment: No but the floor function returns the greatest integer less than or equal to a number. The greatest integer that is less than or equal to $-5/3=-1.666\dots$ is $-2$.

Comment: Floor of $-x$ is $\lfloor -x\rfloor = -\lceil x\rceil$. It is equal to $-\lfloor x\rfloor$ iff $\lceil x\rceil = \lfloor x\rfloor$, i.e. $x$ is an integer.

Comment: @PeterForeman I got it, thank you for help

Comment: @peterwhy thanks for explanation